# angular controller-scope scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body ng-app="app">



<p ng-controller="MessageController">
    {{message}}
</p>




<script src="../../angularv1.min.js"></script>
<script src="message-controller-scope.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


/**
 * Created by Glacier on 2015/7/19.
message-controller-scope.js
 */
function MessageController($scope) {
    $scope.message = "This is a model.";
}
```

The result is {{message}}
Why not show This is a model?
Is there any wrong?

This is a angular controller-scope problem.

Comment: what angular version you use? Also are you see any errors in console?

Comment: version 1.4  The console shows that Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]  and angularjs.map not found. But Chol Nhial's answer solved this problem. Is there other methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('MessageController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 $scope.message = "This is a model.";
}]);
```

More here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Answer (score 0):

You need to create angular module:

```
    angular.module('app')
      .controller('MessageController', MessageController);

    function MessageController($scope) {
        $scope.message = "This is a model.";
    }

    MessageController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```